# Obtain the smoothed hazard estimates

Tags: sas, survival-analysis

How can I obtain a data set or table with the smoothed hazard estimates and the 95% confidence intervals with time which are displayed when I run for example

```
ods graphics on;
proc lifetest data=melanoma34 plots=(h(cl));
  time weeks*censor(1);
run;
```

**EDIT**
This is what I run

```
data melanoma34;
  infile '/folders/myfolders/amsus/data/melanoma34.dat';
  input weeks status$;
  if status='alive' then censor=1;
     else censor=0;
run;

Proc lifetest data=Melanoma34 outsurv=hazards;
  time weeks*censor(1);
ods output hazardplot=smoothedhazard;
run;
```

and the `hazards` `outsurv` does not contain the smoothed hazard estimates

[image]. The data can be found [here](http://support.sas.com/publishing/bbu/zip/amsus.zip) under `/amsus/data/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outsurv data set contains the hazard function estimates and the confidence interval.

```
Proc lifetest data=Melanoma outsurv=hazards;
```

EDIT:
The above generates an estimate for the hazard function, not the smoothed estimate and only works for method=LT.

To obtain the smooth estimate, using method=KM (default), then use the following line:

```
ods output hazardplot=smoothedhazard;
```

Final code:

```
data melanoma34;
  infile '/folders/myfolders/amsus/data/melanoma34.dat';
  input weeks status$;
  if status='alive' then censor=1;
     else censor=0;
run;

Proc lifetest data=Melanoma34 plots=h(cl));
  time weeks*censor(1);
ods output hazardplot=smoothedhazard;
run;
```

Comment: the hazards outsurv dataset contains only the survival estimates and their CIs, not the hazards.

Comment: What version of SAS are you on?

Comment: 9.4 University edition. Still doesnt work. Please note I dont need a plot of the hazard but a data set with the smoothed hazard at various time points (similar to the outsurv for the survival)

Comment: The ODS output statement didn't work? You should get a generated dataset called smoothedhazard with the ODS output statement. I tested it with SAS UE and it worked.

Comment: Should the ods statement be before or after the proc? Could you please post the code in one chunk so that I can try to reproduce from my side?

Comment: Within the procedure, somewhere between the proc and run statement.

Comment: It does not seem to work. The hazards data set does not contain any smoothed hazard estimates. I have updated the question with what code I run. Perhaps I am doing something wrong?

Comment: You have to include the plot option from your original code as well or the dataset is not generated at all.